# Reading, parsing and storing .txt files contents in Torch tensors efficiently

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, lua, torch

I have a huge number of .txt files (maybe around 10 millions) each having the same number of rows/colums. They actually are some single channel images and the pixel values are separated with an space. Here's the code I've written to do the work but it's very slow. I wonder if someone can suggest a more optimized/efficient way of doing this:

```
require 'torch'

f = assert(io.open(txtFilePath, 'r'))
local tempTensor = torch.Tensor(1, 64, 64):fill(0)
local i = 1
for line in f:lines() do
    local l = line:split(' ')
    for key, val in ipairs(l) do
        tempTensor[{1, i, key}] = tonumber(val)
    end
    i = i + 1
end
f:close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In brief, change you source files if it is possible.

The only I can suggest is to use binary data instead of txt as a source.
You have got the long-term methods: `f:lines()`, `line:split(' ')` and `tonumber(val)`. All of them are using strings as variables.

As I understood, you have got file like this:

> 0 10 20
>
> 11 18 22
>
> ....

so, change your source it into binary like this:

> <0><18><20><11><18><22> ...

where `<18>` is a byte in hex form, that is `12` , `<20>` is 16 , etc.

to read

```
fid = io.open(sup_filename, "rb")
while true do
  local bytes = fid:read(1)
  if bytes == nil then break end -- EOF
  local st = bytes[0]
  print(st)
end

fid:close()
```

https://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.2.html
It would be dramatically faster.

May be using regular expressions (instead of `:split()` and `lines()`) can help to you but I do not think.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reasons I cannot change the file format to binary. For now, I should find a faster solution to read the original files.

Comment: This is not possible, imo. `io` is rather fast. May be SSD could help.